# Present continuous tense and the population of the world (e.g.)

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous

We say "The population of the world is increasing very fast".

Can we say that using present simple tense? I'm confused with that, because the increase of human population is a thing that happens permanently. Every day.

So, can we say that like "The population of the world increases very fast"? 
And if so, what's the difference between these two?

Comment: I think the difference would be: (increasing) - the current situation, happening at the moment; (increases) - a statement of fact or idea.

Comment: *"The increase of human population is a thing that happens permanently.  Every day"* - not quite every day.  Estimates are that 150k people die each day, with about 350k born, so any natural disaster in which more than 200k people die is likely a net loss.  [Several would qualify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_natural_disasters_by_death_toll#Ten_deadliest_natural_disasters_since_1900) from history alone, not counting future possibilities...

Comment: Yes, I second @shin on this. The present tense is often used to talk 'facts'. *Birds fly!*  **not** *'Birds are flying'*

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I don't have any questions about this anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Grammar in Use, we tend to use present continuous to describe ***current*** global problems as in your sentence.

Although I think this distinction falls under a more general category which is the usage of present continuous to describe **an action happening around now** as in

> I'm getting fat.
>
> The climate is getting warmer.
>
> I'm learning spanish.

Yes, *increasing population rapidly* is happening everyday but it's not something that has been around for a very long time. Actually we can say *it's happening **everyday these days***.

When you say, *"The population of the world is increasing very fast"*

1. You emphasize that this is going on **right now** and it's perceived like a **warning**
2. You say it's happening at your time and it's a **current** phenomenon.

Comment: Glad you found it useful 